# How to get simple html form to post to db

Tags: php

I have a website that has accounts and I want so that the user can submit anything they write in the text box to the db (database).  I also want them to see what they have posted after it gets to the database.

Here is the PHP:

```
mysqli_query($db_conx, "INSERT INTO comments(WebsiteSubmit) 
    VALUES('$comment',now())");

$comment = $_POST['websitesubmit'];

header ("location: form.html");
```

And the form:

```
<form action="index.php" method="post" />
  <input type="text" id="comment" name="WebsiteSubmit" />
  <input type="submit" class="submit" value=" Submit Comment " /> 
</form
```

I know its a very easy question but I am new to php and having a hard time googling this stuff.

Thanks.

Comment: you didn't post the PHP

Comment: Watch your cases: `websitesubmit` is not the same as `WebsiteSubmit`. Also, you need to initialise the variable you're using in your query _before_ you execute the query. Side-note: you should use `mysqli_real_escape_string()` to escape your user inputs or you are susceptible to SQL injection attacks.

Comment: No offence, but this is not even a half-serious attempt at solving the problem, just some random lines of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should make it one page unless you want to mess with querying data from database:

```
<?php
    if(empty($_POST)) { ?>
        <form action="" method="post" >
            <input type="text" id="comment" name="WebsiteSubmit" />
            <input type="submit" class="submit" value=" Submit Comment " />
        </form>
    <?php } else {
        $comment = $_POST['websitesubmit'];
        mysqli_query($db_conx, "INSERT INTO comments(WebsiteSubmit) 
VALUES('$comment',now())");
        echo $comment;
    }
```